# history.pushState and window.onpopstate over various pages

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser-history, html5-history

I have a page where the content is changed using AJAX and the URL is updated using history.pushstate. After some updates, going back and forward between them is also working properly, thanks to window.onpopstate.

The code for the onpopstate is:

```
window.onpopstate = function (e) {
  if (e.state) {
    if (e.state.type == 'product-detail' && $('.product-container').length == 1) {
      updateProductDetail(e.state.html);
    }
    else {
      location.reload();
    }
  }
};
```

So I check whether I should use the pop state and whether I am still on the page where I can reapply the update information (the html data as returned by the AJAX call). If not (i.e. I am on another page and cannot apply the update here) I reload the whole page using the new Url (which is the url stored with the pushed state).

This all works as expected, except when I go to another page from this page and then press back. Chrome only shows the contents of the AJAX request, i.e. only the updated information, without anything else (so no js, css, whatever).
Firefox seems to load the whole page and continues to use the onpopstate if pressing back again. Chrome just seems to go back and only show the data received by the AJAX request.
I have tried putting the whole page (document.documentElement.outerHTML) in the pushed state's "html" property, but to no avail.

PS: Using Chrome's debugger, I can see that the window.onpopstate is not fired when pressing 'back' from the second page.

Comment: I have the exact same issue and I am wondering, how did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you have already find a solution.
If not, take a look at the documentation

[Location reload() Method on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp)

Particularly this part :

> Syntax
>
> location.reload(forceGet)
>
> Parameter Values
>
> forceGet   Boolean Optional.
>
> Specifies the type of reloading:
>   false - Default. Reloads the current page from the cache.
>   true - The current page must be reloaded from the server

So try this code in the "else" part :

```
location.reload(true);
```